# Azure Logic Apps Starting Limitation Work Around?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Looking for some assistance with this Logic App as I appear to have hit some sort of limitation.

I have a logic app that pull in the properties of 10 different container groups. From there I have built logic using "Conditions" to check and see if the Container Group(s) are "Running". If the Container Group is not running, then I start the Container Group and the process ends.

If they are running, then the logic app proceeds to the next Container Group and does the same check and on and on we go until we reach Container Group 10.

The issue I am running into now is that on the sixth Container Group I can no longer Add An Action to the Logic App. I believe I hit a limitation with Logic Apps so I am seeking some suggestions on how to navigate around this... Attaching some sample here to show you what I am doing:
[logicappexample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZjF2.png)

Comment: For reference the limits are defined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/pim-configure). It is only possible to nest 8 actions in total.

Comment: Thanks... I think you linked the PIM page but I found what you're saying here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config?tabs=azure-portal

Answer (score 2):

Based on your screenshot, it seems you can take advantage of "ForEach" in "Control" connector, to cycle through 10 different containers:

["ForEach" in "Control" connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAlDR.png)

In order to break the loop, use a flag variable which can be set to false to prevent further runs.
I'm hoping this will free up Actions to be added to the logic app.

Comment: First and foremost thanks for responding.

I have been messing around about with what you're suggesting here of the past couple days. I scrapped what I had and pulled the container state into a ForEach. The part I am missing is how to loop through the state and verify the container is running. I am trying to use a results expression but it's not working as expected.

Code:

result('Foreach') is equal to Running

Comment: You are supposed to loop through the container groups instead of looping through the state. It would help, if you can provide how you are fetching the `state` from the properties of container groups, or how you are looping through the container groups.

Comment: Gotcha... 

So in this case I am pulling down all the properties of my container groups in parallel.

Then I want to drill into the `state` of each container group. If the container group is `Running` I want to move on to the next container group and check if it's running and on and on looping through all 10 container groups until I find one that is not `Running`.

Once I found the one that is NOT `Running` I want to `Start` it and then exit the loop. 

The previous workflow I had did this but as previously stated I met an issue with the nested loop limitations.